# Visual Studio unwanted restores settings

Tags: visual-studio

i posted this problem already the VS community but so far i got not really
help. They said will be fixed next release, however, the problem returns sooner or later.

When i start visual studio, it always resets settings. I use a different font
and colours.

This is a problem i had first time with Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 but it is getting worse with all newer Visual Studios.

Right now i am using Visual Studio 2017 15.8.1.

Meanwhile i need to load saved settings each time  i open a project.
Replacing the 'original ' ? settings in

C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Settings

has no effect.

Before doing a complete reinstallation which is quite expensive on my machine,
i ask this forum:
Where are the default settings stored or how to resolve this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: have you noticed a pattern when it happens? Like when you log in visual studio, opening a specific kind of file or something else?

Comment: No. But i guess it is somehow related to open projects created with older versions of Visual Studio and you have another instance of Visual Studio opened with a newer project. It would be interesting to know, where those settings are stored. As i wrote in my post, i replaced the default settings with my exported settings. But when opening a new instance, the standard settings seem to take affeect. So from where those standard settings loaded ?